# How do I implement the clock into this testbench?

Tags: verilog, clock, adder, testbench

I am trying to write a testbench for an adder/subtractor, but when it compiles, the clock does not shift.

Here is the Verilog code for the adder/subtractor:

```
module adder_sub(

input [7:0] dataa,
input [7:0] datab,
input add_sub,
                        // if this is 1, add; else subtract
input clk,

output reg [8:0] result);

    always @ (posedge clk)
        begin
            if (add_sub)
                result <= dataa + datab;
            else
                result <= dataa - datab;
        end
endmodule
```

And here is the code for the testbench:

```
module adder_sub_tb;

    reg[7:0]dataa;
    reg[7:0]datab;
    reg add_sub;
    reg clk;
    wire[8:0]result;
    
    adder_sub dut (.dataa(dataa), .datab(datab), .add_sub(add_sub), .clk(clk), .result(result));
    
    initial begin
    dataa <= 8'b00000000;
    datab <= 8'b111111111;
    end
    
    
    always@(clk) begin
        clk = 1;
        #20;
        clk = 0;
        #20;
    end
    
    always @(posedge clk) begin
    
    repeat(16) begin
        add_sub = 1'b0;
            $display(result);
        #10;
        
        add_sub = 1'b1;
            $display(result);
        #10;
            
        dataa = dataa + 1'b1;
        datab = datab - 1'b1;
        
        end 
        end 
        
        endmodule
```

This compiles just fine, but in the simulation, the clock does not change at all, and I don't know how to fix it.

I am using modelsim-altera as my simulation tool and quartus prime lite for verilog.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is with this block:

```
always@(clk) begin
    clk = 1;
    #20;
    clk = 0;
    #20;
end
```

It will only run when clk is high, since you have @(clk) as the sensitivity list at the beginning of the block. A more typical way to generate your clock is this:

```
initial clk = 0;
always #20 clk = ~clk;
```

Actually, though, your original code might work fine if you just remove the sensitivity to clk, changing it to:

```
always begin
    clk = 1;
    #20;
    clk = 0;
    #20;
end
```